Sync to/from local folder to hard drive MacOS
I was wondering if there is a way to sync a (local) folder with an external LaCie HDD with a local folder on connect (or on running a shell script).
I am using MacOS
Other details:

This is an external hdd connected through USB-C
The drive is password protected and uses the GUID partition map and follows APFS (encrypted)
the hard drive won't always be connected (hence, the point of this system)

Thank you for your help.

Define "Sync" - is this a one way copy (always overwrite) or do you edit the files on both locations, does the sync have to be automatic or are you going to manually trigger it, do you care if the data on the external drive looks identical to the primary or can it be stored in a backup format?

Google “rsync”, it is awesome and can do this. Install it, practice with it (it has lots of options), then put the command and arguments/options into a shell script to run manually. Resubmit a different question after that’s working to ask about triggering it on connect.

In response to DavidT, I'm thinking more of a git style copy without having to have a git server and using extra space for all of that. Which is to say: compare all files who's contents was modified last and keep the newest one. Not sure how deleting would really work though...
Edit: I will definitely look into rsync thank you for the suggestion
